# Haskell: function parse error at the beginning

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner in haskell and trying to do a cipher validate function.

```
 validateCipher :: [Char] -> Bool
 validateCipher cipher =
       if length $ nub cipher == length cipher  
        then return True
        else return False
```

When I run it through ghci, it just told me: **error: parse error on input ‘validateCipher’**.
Not sure what is going wrong, should I add Eq or any stuff(I don't quite sure what does it do either)?

Comment: remove the `return`. In Haskell there is no `return` keyword, there is only a `return` function. Furthermore the `$` results in parsing it as `length (nub cipher == length cipher), so you should use brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors here:

1. you use `return`. In Haskell there is *no* `return` *keyword*, there is a [**`return :: Monad a => a -> m a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return) function, but that works differently; and
2. the `$` results in the fact that `length $ nub cipher == length cipher` is parsed as `length (nub cipher == length cipher)`, and that does not satisfy the type constraints, since `nub cipher` returns a `[Char]`, whereas `length cipher`, will return an `Int`.

We do not need `return True`, or `True` in the first place here, since we can just return the outcome of the condition we check. We can furthermore use parenthesis to write a correct expression:

```
validateCipher :: [Char] -> Bool
validateCipher cipher = length (nub cipher) == length cipher
```

Comment: Q1 The reason is that I did search and found somebody used return True in Haskell..... Thank you so much for a more reliable answer.

Comment: @GTTT: well for monadic computations, like `IO`, `Maybe`, etc. one can indeed sometimes use `return`. But not for non-monadic ones, like the one here.

Comment: Q2 I didnt fully understand the $ operator, but now because of your explanations I would be more confident of that! thx a lot

Comment: @GTTT: `($)` is an operator that has very low precedence (https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html), it is basically used to group the part at the left, and the part at the right, and make a function application. So `... $ ...`, is nearly always equivalent to `(...) (...)` (but without brackets).